# UITableView Cells separated by dotted lines

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'd like to change the separator from a UITableView to a dotted line. All I could find is 
UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleBlabla...

Can I put something else instead? I'd rather not use images, but if there is no other way...

Thanks!

Comment: create a label with with text @"--" or @"..." and fill the screen with the text color you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the solutions below:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dottedlineimage"]];
```

**note**:Don't forget to turn off the default separator style for the table view in ***both the solutions***: `[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];`

=====================OR TRY THIS===========================================

```
UIImageView *aLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
 [aLine setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourDottedImage.png"]];
 [cell.contentView addSubview:aLine];
 [aLine release];
```

H appy to help:)

Comment: I prefer using the first one,because if you use checkmark,the contentView will give place to it and shrink to left.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no separator as a dotted line. 
You could create own separator by appending image to the end of custom cell.