# Draw dotted border bottom for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like add an dotted bottom border to my `UITableViewCell`.

Currently, I am using the following code,

```
    CAShapeLayer *border = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    border.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:67/255.0f green:37/255.0f blue:83/255.0f alpha:1].CGColor;
    border.fillColor = nil;
    border.lineDashPattern = @[@1, @1];
    border.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cell.bounds].CGPath;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x, cell.bounds.origin.y + cell.bounds.size.height, cell.bounds.size.width, 1);
    [cell.layer addSublayer:border];
```

With this code I have a dotted border bottom for my cell but the height of the dotted border is two time too big.

But I'm not very good to manipulate `CAShapeLayer` and I didn't find anything to help me.

Thanks !

Comment: Where do you put this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's the stroke that's too wide, try changing your layer's `lineWidth`. Something like this will do the trick:

```
border.lineWidth = 1. / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

That'll draw a 1px line on non-Retina devices, and a 1px line (0.5pt) on Retina ones, resulting in an ultra-crisp line.

Also, you could build your path with just a single line instead of a rect using `moveToPoint` and `addLineToPoint` on a `UIBezierPath`:

```
UIBezierPath *bPath = [UIBezierPath new];
[bPath moveToPoint:CGPointZero];
[bPath addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){100, 0}];
border.path = bPath.CGPath;
```

Adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

create custom cell and set your border to bottom of custom cell

```
/* drow line bottom */
cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:67/255.0f green:37/255.0f blue:83/255.0f alpha:1].CGColor;
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
```

or..

other wise check the bellow link they give answer to set cell bellow image 
[UITableView Cells separated by dotted lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261602/uitableview-cells-separated-by-dotted-lines)

Comment: Could you explain to me how you think to do this ? I've just edited my first post.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ with full detail how to create custom cell in ios check it and as above you are creating doted line create same as for custom cell in bottom